# Image of a transformation becomes a Hilbert space !!

Tags: complex-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, harmonic-analysis

Let $T: L^2(\mathbb R)\to O(\mathbb C)$ an transformation from the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb R)$ to the Fréchet spaces $O(\mathbb C)$ of all holomorphic functions on $\mathbb C$. We assume that $T$ is injective and continuous.

Now, Can we endowed the space $\mathcal H:= Im T$ (image of $T$) with the Hilbert inner product
from $\left(L^{2}(\mathbb{R}), \left<.,.\right>\right)$ for that $\mathcal H:= Im T$ becomes a Hilbert space of holomorphic functions ? If yes, how?

**I think it is possible if we consider the inner product $(f,g)_{\mathcal H}=\left<T^{-1}(f),T^{-1}(g)\right>_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R})}$ ??**

Thank you in advance

Comment: I suspect that you need the inverse of $T$ to be continuous in order to guarantee completeness. This is not the case in general.

Comment: @ Martin, we have assume that $T$  is injective and continuous. Then, $T$ becomes an isomorphism continuous from $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ to $Im T$.

Comment: Yes but take a Cauchy sequence in the image. You now need to show that it's convergent. Now the you'd like to map that Cauchy sequence back to $L^2$ in order to use completeness of this space. However we hit a wall - the inverse is not necessarily continuous - thus elements close to each other in $H$ need not be close in $L^2$. I'm not saying it's not doable just that we might need continuity of $T^{-1}$ that's all :)

Comment: @  Martin, I think it is possible if we consider the inner product $(f,g)_{\mathcal H}=\left<T^{-1}(f),T^{-1}(g)\right>_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R})}$ ??